# Handling empty action in $.ajax function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, html

I want to load evrything in my website inside a div, so i created a function to handle form submissions to make the action loads in the same div, however the problem is some forms don't have action `action=""` as the script is in the same page, so when i submit the form nothing happen inisde the div, so how i can handle this in my function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              $('#mydiv').delegate('form', 'submit', function() { // catch the form's submit events inside the div
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
             //$('#mydiv').html(response); // update the DIV
            $('#mydiv').fadeOut('slow',function() {
                        $('#collabsoft').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
                });
              //  return false;
}
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary if statement:

```
url: $(this).attr('action') == '' ? window.location : $(this).attr('action')
```

Comment: you should not make ajax calls to the same page unless you can target specific data in sed page. ajax will return whats been rendered so if u get data from the same page you will also get things like head tags, script tags, etc. etc.

Comment: That's not true. You can easily create a page that spits out content that depends upon what data you send to it.

Comment: @Blender can you tell me, how i can do that?

Comment: @SamerElGendy By sending a specific parameter to that page (`data: { param: true }` for example). And in the page itself, check if this parameters exists. If so, do whatever you want to do. -- But I find this dirty. I usually create a specific route (or file, if you do it this way), for each Ajax treatment.